# Entity framework with Include method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have issue with Include Method , scenario as given

Table Warehouse has columns

1. Id--> unique identifier and PK
2. warehouseNumber--nvarchar(50)

--some more columns

Table  WarehouselnkedEcorders

1. Id-->PK,unique Identifier
2. warehouseUniqueId-->(FK,Unique Identifier), It has relationship with "Warehouse" table Id column
3. Status

Warehouse Model has following Code

```
public class Warehouse
{
    public Warehouse()
    {
        this.WarehouselnkedEcorders = new List<WarehouselnkedEcorder>();
    }
    //Some stuff

    public virtual ICollection<WarehouselnkedEcorder> WarehouselnkedEcorders 
    { get; set; }
}
```

WarehouselnkedEcOrdeMap has following Code

```
        // Relationships
        this.HasOptional(t => t.Warehouse)
            .WithMany(t => t.WarehouselnkedEcorders)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.warehouseUniqueId);
```

Query

I need to retrive a list of warehouse entity with status=true. I tried the following way,but could not get result. How can I do this?

```
  List<Warehouse> lstObjWarehouse = objWMSContext.Warehouses.Include("WarehouselnkedEcorders").Where(//o=>SomeCondition)
                                                       .Where(o => SomeCondition)
                                                       .Where(o => o.Deleted == false).ToList();
```

Here I need to compare value of status=true of each row of  "WarehouselnkedEcorder" and it should return result.

Comment: How many of a `Warehouse`'s related `WarehouselnkedEcorder`s must have a true `Status` to include the `Warehouse` in the result set?

Comment: have you tried `"WarehouselnkedEcorders"` instead of `"WarehouselnkedEcorder"`?

Comment: @lante: I have included "WarehouselnkedEcorders".

Comment: in your code, you didn't write the "s" in the Include statment. if so, please edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Any in query:

```
List<Warehouse> lstObjWarehouse = db.Warehouses.Include("WarehouselnkedEcorder")
.Where(o => o.invoicePath == "SomeCondition" 
&& o.Deleted == false 
&& o.WarehouselnkedEcorders.Any(p => p.id == o.id 
&& p.Deleted == false)).ToList();
```

Comment: It works by changing navigation property name to "WarehouselnkedEcorders"

Answer (score 0):

Fixed to match 1:many condition

```
List<Warehouse> lstObjWarehouse =   objWMSContext.Warehouses.Include("WarehouselnkedEcorder")
                    .Where(o => o.somefield == "SomeCondition"
                  &&       o => o.Deleted == false
                  &&       o=>o.WarehouselnkedEcorders.Where(dep=>dep.status==true)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: It supposed to get  o=>o.WarehouselnkedEcorders.status == true. But it shows WarehouselnkedEcorders as a list with methods like Any,Where,etc.